# Ionic CLI not updating on MAC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I have been trying to update Ionic CLI, I can use the install from NPM and it says it is installing version 2, but if I run Ionic --v it returns 1.7.15. I am guessing it is installed locally, but not sure how I can remove it to let it use the updated global one. I have tried manually deleting from the user node_modules and that. Any ideas?

Comment: It's happens for me too, anything to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to run `npm install -g ionic@2.2.2` in terminal and it will update the global version of ionic.

If that doesn't work then just remove ionic (`npm uninstall -g ionic`) and install again using the command above.